# Optimal JPEG compression for frames extracted from video

Tags: video, compression, jpeg, video-processing

I have a small mp4 of a 6 second [vine video](https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/v/videos/9B1DBCDC-2509-4CF8-BC46-E67B02C944B9-2870-00000137A369D3B8_1.0.5.mp4?versionId=r9WMhDwkkYFSNW24sJbGJ0Pg9KUzSQhH). The total size on disk is about 840kb.

I wrote a little script to extract the frames at 20fps as JPEG (with compression quality of 0.8).

After running the script I got about 130 JPEGs around 22kb each. The combined compressed size hovers around 2.6 Mb.

What can be done to reduce the size down to the video's original size? I don't know much about video/image processing so please enlighten me on why this happens and the mistakes I'm making.

**Additional Info**: The video/image dimensions are 480x480.

Answer (score 4):

I'am not sure to understand the question but for me it is a compression mistake.

Mp4
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4

Jpeg
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpg

Jpeg only compress spacial redundancy but mp4 allow to compress both spacial and temporal redundancy then it seems normal that mp4 is lighter than insides jpeg images ?

Have a look on this :
[How does MPEG4 compression work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593649/how-does-mpeg4-compression-work)

Good luck !