# Best way to transfer a large number of BMP images

Tags: bmp, image-compression, compression, video-compression

On a remote machine, I have a number of BMP images that I want to transfer to my computer as fast as possible. These images are **very** similar (frames from a single scene in a video). I do not want to lose **any** information.

I tried zipping but zipping just takes ~30-40% of the size and takes time too. I had the idea to convert images to video using some lossless video format, transfer the file and than decode but it seems like the size gets to ~40-50% of original and the process takes time.

I believe this problem has to have better solution (because of image similarity) but I am still not able to find it. Please share your ideas. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using video. Here is an SO answer that does a good job in describing MPEG4: [How does MPEG4 compression work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593649/how-does-mpeg4-compression-work) . Video codecs that compress the footage usually convert to YUV (also stated in the referenced answer), and the only store the difference, thus greatly reducing file size overall. H.264 is a great example: people use it more, because it saves on (drumrolls) bandwidth, because of its good compression algorithm.